# QlikView:Using dimensions value in expression

Tags: qlikview

I am trying to figure out how can I use dimension values as one of the set modifiers in Expressions in qlikview. Consider the following:

```
Raw Data:
PName, count
AB,2
BC,3
CD,4

Dimension:
Name

Expression:
SUM(<{PName=Name}>count)
```

i-e using the dimension value as one of the set modifiers.

Thanks

Comment: Could please define what you mean by dimension?  I ask because the only dimension in your raw data is `PName` and you reference `Name` which isn't defined anywhere.  If `Name` is linked to `PName` in another table and you have a `Name` listbox on your dashboard, you simply do `sum(count)` and select the values for `Name` in the listbox. If that won't work for your use case, please provide more info on what `Name` is in your context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @bdiamante said. It is not clear what you exactly want to do.

But I assume that you only want to use the current value of the dimension to calculate the count of names.
If that is true, then you can simply say:

```
Expression:
=sum(count)
```

HTH

Answer (score 1):

I believe I understand. Try `sum({<Pname=p(Name)>}count)`. This says that `pname` will be the possible values of `name`. Also look into `e()` which is the excluded values.

Answer (score 0):

If Name is a literal value, try this:

```
sum({<PName={'AB'}>}count)
```

It would always give you the count as if someone had selected PName = 'AB'.

If you only want it to show the count for AB, if AB has not been excluded based on the current selections (e.g. someone has selected PName of 'BC'), then use:

```
sum({<PName*={'AB'}>}count)
```

This will give you the count for AB, but only if AB is included in scope for (i.e. intersects with) the current selections.